# Работа с формами. JS

Tags: javascript, формы

Нигде не могу найти ответа.
Допустим у меня есть данная форма:

```
<form class="formDima">
    <input type="text"  name="1">
    <input type="text"  name="2">
    <input type="text"  name="3">
    <input type="text"  name="4">
    <input type="submit" value="Ок">
</form>
```

Я хочу, чтобы по клику submit создавался объект с введенными данными в форму. И данный объект добавлялся в массив. Чтобы при новом клике создался новый объект....
Подскажите источники или примерно как это можно реализовать.
спасибо.

Comment: Куда вы данные формы отправлять хотите?

Comment: @Anamnian ни куда . просто нужно сохранить их в массив для дальнейшей работы с ним

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_input(form){
   let els = document.querySelectorAll(form+' [name]'),
       arr = [];
   for(let i=0; i<els.length; i++){
    arr[els[i].name] = els[i].value
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Когда нужно получить данные с формы в виде массива, вызываем функцию `get_input`, где в качестве аргумента указываем селектор формы и получаем объект ( ассоциативный массив). Если какой-то элемент формы не нужен, просто в нем не указываем атрибут name

```
get_input('.formDima');
```

Answer (score 0):

Формы предназначены для отправки данных на сервер. В вашем же случае форму использовать нет смысла.

```js
var data = [];
function savedata(){
  let item = {
    1: $('input[name=1]').val(),
    2: $('input[name=2]').val(),
    3: $('input[name=3]').val(),
    4: $('input[name=4]').val(),
  };
  data.push(item);
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="1">
<input type="text" name="2">
<input type="text" name="3">
<input type="text" name="4">
<input type="button" onclick="savedata()" value="Ок">
```

После клика по кнопке в массив записывается объект с указанными полями, и в консоли выводится весь массив объектов.